# Nginx - Exactly 500 requests per second - How to increase it?

Tags: nginx

```
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log crit;
events {
        worker_connections 4000;
        multi_accept on;
        use epoll;
}

http {
        include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        directio 4m;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        client_body_buffer_size 15K;
        client_max_body_size 8m;

        keepalive_timeout 20;
        client_body_timeout 15;
        client_header_timeout 15;
        send_timeout 10;

        open_file_cache max=5000 inactive=20s;
        open_file_cache_valid 60s;
        open_file_cache_min_uses 5;
        open_file_cache_errors off;

        gzip on;
        gzip_comp_level 2;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/xjavascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

The server has 8 cores and 32 gb ram.
The load is 0.05
But nginx is not able to handle more than 500 requests per second.
How to change to config to make nginx to get more than 500 requests per second?

sysctl.conf
I have already made some changes in the config file

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 2
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 16777216
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 16384 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 60
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 20
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 300
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 10000
net.core.somaxconn = 2048
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 2048
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 15000 65000
kernel.pid_max = 65535
```

Comment: Are you certain it's not something else, like hitting the limits of the network connection on the server or your testing tool?

Comment: Is there anything wrong in the settings? The site suddenly went to down status. By that time, the traffic was 1500 per second. I restarted nginx it is not stable in 500 requests

Comment: @Mahesh nginx itself can handle A LOT more than 30,000 rpm by default. You are most likely touching on another bottleneck somewhere. Can you edit your post to show some relevant error logs from nginx or such like to try and diagnose the issue.